# Prevent race-conditions in slug generation with friendly-id and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

In a much used application I am running into problems with the unique database constraint on the slug column.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId

  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged
end
```

A method in Profile calls:

```
  save! if valid?
```

And sometimes this results in `Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry 'evert-159226' for key 'index_profiles_on_slug'`

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow! The problem you're facing is that Rails-side validation doesn't guarantee uniqueness when you perform a save operation. There are basically two way to solve that

1. Issue a table-level lock to avoid other records from being inserted or updated. This will however influence your performance quite heavily
2. Save the object without the slug first and then keep updating it with atomic operations until you're successful.

I can provide you wth example code for both if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for helping. table-level locks are not an option. It is a very heavily used application. I think I will overwrite the #save and retry.

Comment: @gerard Overwriting a save is really really not a smart idea. You should rather go for worse slug first and then update it quickly to something nicer. This could even be done in one roundtrip from browser (i.e. after_commit callback)